# VB .NET Main() in WindowsApplication

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Additional Information:

- Im using Visual Studio 2008 (VB)
- I have experience with C#

I cant see where to define the Main Sub, here is my problem:

I created a WindowsApplication in Visual Studio, it created a Form for me, when i click 'View Code', something like this appears.

```
Public Class Form1
End Class
```

wups, where is the Main Sub and where is the designer generated code?

And the next problem is, that when I delete the `Form1`, an error occurs which says that the `MainForm` isnt set. Double Clicking the error leads me to an `Application.Designer.vb`, which looks like following:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.4927
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = False
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = True
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = True
            Me.ShutdownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApplication1.Form1
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I want to define my own Main Entry Point, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Project + Properties, Application, untick "Enable application framework".  Now you can change the "Startup object" setting.

Comment: @Hans Why is this not an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need application events.
go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in Solution Explorer, choose application tab.
**There you can choose the application startup form.**

To more sophisticated scenarios you need to click on "View Application Event".
This will create an ApplicationEvent.vb

At this class partial you can choose how to startup.
Example:

```
        Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(ByVal eventArgs As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) As Boolean
            Me.MainForm = New Form2
            Return MyBase.OnStartup(eventArgs)
        End Function
```

Comment: this isnt what I needed too, but due to you rpost, I found a solution: under Project Properties - Application, change Console Application to Windows Application

Answer (score 0):

Create a console application and show your form using Form.show in the Main() method.

Comment: But then, everytime the program starts, the console will start too